# How to pass info b/w two angular app as the header of second app's path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have two angular app.In first app i have a button, on click of that button i want to load second app(i.e. index.html file of second app that is on webportal folder)and of course  also change the url.
That i can do simply like this

```
<a href="http://localhost:8000/webportal/">Second App</a>
```

But the catch is i want to add some property in the header of this call and read them in index.html of second app,Adding header,i tried  using request interceptor in first app and making a ajax call, and on the success of this call changing the url using window.open like this

```
`$scope.buttonClicked= function() {
                    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8000/webportal/'}).then(function(data) {
                    window.open(data.config.url,'_self' );  
                                        });
                };
```

`

once the window reload because of window.open i cant see the header that i added using request interceptor of first app.
What should i do to add header in the call for `"http://localhost:8000/webportal/"` and read that header in index.html of second app.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass headers this way

```
    var config = {
        //other than headers you can pass info from here
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'your token'
            'Accept': 'application/json;'
       //If you have any headers you can specify here
        }
    };
   $http.get('http://localhost:8000/webportal/',config)
    .success(function(data){
        window.open(data.config.url,'_self' ); 
 });
```

Comment: Thanks,but this is what i am already doing,but once the window.open reload the page no header is shown.